# Pass environment variable to dockerfile build

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to create a service consisting of a web server and database all in docker containers. Currently I am trying to create same environment file for both of them that would contain database credentials. Unfortunatelly, when I try to build database with it, it turns out that they are empty. How can I create a project with single environment file for both components? Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-db
    ports:
      - '5433:5432'
    env_file:
      - env
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    command: venv/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - env
```

Here is part of my Dockerfile-db file responsible for creating database:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.2

USER postgres

ARG DB_PASSWORD
ARG DB_NAME

RUN echo $DB_PASSWORD

RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start && \
    psql --command "ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD '$DB_PASSWORD';" && \
    psql --command "CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME;" && \
    psql --command "\\c $DB_NAME" && \
    psql --command "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;" && \
    psql --command "CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;"
```

And my env file has following structure:

```
DB_NAME=some_name
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=some_password
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=5432
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The environment file is not part of the build process, it is used when running the container.

You need to use build-args. In docker-compose you can specify build args in the file:

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-db
  args:
    DB_NAME: some_name
    DB_USER: postgress
    ...
```

This might not be a good idea if you want to publish the composefile, as you are storing credentials in it. You can explicitly build and pass `--build-arg`

```
docker-compose build --build-arg DB_NAME= some_name ...
```

And when running specify no build in `docker-compose run --no-build`

**Update:**

As suggested by @gonczor, a shorter and cleaner syntax to use pass the env file as build args is:

```
docker-compose build --build-args $(cat envfile)
```

Comment: I keep getting this message as if the `--build-arg` was not supported. Can it be due to `docker-compose` version? (I'm running 1.8)


    Usage: build [options] [SERVICE...]
    
    Options:
        --force-rm  Always remove intermediate containers.
        --no-cache  Do not use cache when building the image.
        --pull      Always attempt to pull a newer version of the image.

Comment: Yes possibly. If `docker-compose build --help` is not showing `--build-arg` option, you need to update docker compose

Comment: Thanks for help. It worked. And I've come up with a workaround. I've just added `--build-args $(cat env)` to the command. If you were so kind to add it to the answer I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is correct, it seems like you may not be passing the actual path or the name of the `.env` file. Have you tried the following (assuming your .env file is in the same directory).

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-db
    ports:
      - '5433:5432'
    env_file:
      - ./.env
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    command: venv/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - ./.env
```